# Why is event.preventDefault() able to prevent default browser behavior for child element?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, preventdefault, event-propagation

I understand that `event.preventDefault()` can prevent browser default behavior, but why does it work if you put this on parent element's event handler?

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  alert('parent click');
  //e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();   
  
});

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  alert('click');
  //e.stopPropagation();
  //e.preventDefault(); 
  //return true;
  
  });
```

```css
.foo{
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id ="parent">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <div id="button" class="foo" tabindex='-1'> hello </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

If you click the button, there is no navigation. Why does it work?

Comment: The event bubbles, so it can be caught by any handler up the ancestor chain. It only gets executed at the very top.

Comment: right, I think my confusion was that i thought the logic to decide whether a default action should be executed is in the event handler on the action element. But seems like that logic happens after when the event finishes the bubbling, and as long as the event.defaultPrevented is true in the end, the default behavior will be canceled.  thanks , vlaz~

Answer (score 0):

Because that is the way how the DOM structure works. In this case, the button is a part of the parent. Therefore a click on the button is also a click on the parent, and therefore both onclicks will be triggered. Note that the onclicks will be triggered from the bottom up, meaning the buttons event will be triggered first, after which it's parent gets triggered, after which the parent of the parent will get an onclick event and so on.

If this results in an unwanted result you can prevent this behavior by, as i think you already noticed, the `event.stopPropagation()` function. If this method is called the event will not be triggered on the parents from that element upward.